# Forwarding a request to intended route after form submit

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route defined `/user/password/reset` which I'm protecting with two factor authentication middleware.

When you visit this route, the middleware interrupts, sends a code to the email/sms and presents a 2FA validation page. This all works well.

When the user enters the confirmation code, the form posts to my 2FA validate route which currently forwards the request to `/home`. I've lost the original request at this point.

I feel like Laravel has some pretty clean solutions to these types of problems but I can't seem to find anything. Outside of storing the intended route in the Session, is there a way to get the original route after the form has been submitted?

I can provide code if required, but not sure it's needed.

Thanks

Comment: There is `redirect()->intended()` which should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Do note that `intended ` can also take an argument as the route name, so there's that.

Comment: @Tuim When I place that as the redirect at the end of the method that's posted to, to validate the 2FA code, it send me to / instead of the actual intended route. I can figure out why.

Comment: You need to either set the session variable before/during the validate 2FA request or redirect to the 2FA request with the intended function in the chain